# Is it safe to cast SOCKET to int under Win64?

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets

I’m working on a Windows port of a POSIX C++ program.

The problem is that standard POSIX  functions like accept() or bind() expect an ‘int’ as the first parameter while its WinSock counterparts use ‘SOCKET’.
When compiled for 32-bit everything is fine, because both are 32bit, but under Win64 SOCKET is 64 bit and int remains 32 bit and it generates a lot of compiler warning like this:
`warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'SOCKET' to 'int', possible loss of data`

I tried to work around the issue by using a typedef:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
 typedef SOCKET sock_t;
#else
 typedef int sock_t;
#endif
```

and replacing ‘int’s with sock_t at the appropriate places.

This was fine until I reached a part of the code which calls OpenSSL APIs.
As it turned out OpenSSL uses ints for sockets even on Win64. That seemed really strange, so I started searching for an answer, but the only thing I found was an old post on the openssl-dev mailing list which refered to a comment e_os.h:

```
/*
 * Even though sizeof(SOCKET) is 8, it's safe to cast it to int, because
 * the value constitutes an index in per-process table of limited size
 * and not a real pointer.
 */
```

So my question is:
is it really safe to cast SOCKET to int?
I’d like to see some kind of documentation which proves that values for SOCKET can't be larger than 2^32.
Thanks in advance!
Ryck

Comment: The OpenSSL bug "MINGW-W64 and SOCKET type (should not be int) #7282" created Sep 2018 by JPeterMugaas seems to be the same issue: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7282.  As of Jan 2021, it's currently being ignored.

Comment: There is also this 2019 version of the same bug "windows x64 uses SOCKET (64bit) instead of int (32 bit) as descriptor. BIO_new_socket takes int #8169" https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/8169.  The issue reporter leleftheriades decided to close the issue almost immediately because he decided the OpenSSL maintainers won't fix the issue until it actually breaks something. Sad.

Comment: Nitpick: AFAIK identifier names ending in `_t` (like your `sock_t`) are reserved for the implementation and you are, technically, not allowed to create such names in user code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [post](http://arkiv.netbsd.se/?ml=openssl-dev&a=2008-03&t=6812712) seems by the to be repeating the information on [kernel objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724485(VS.85).aspx) at msdn:

> Kernel object handles are process specific. That is, a process must either create the object or open an existing object to obtain a kernel object handle. The per-process limit on kernel handles is 2^24.

The thread goes on to cite [Windows Internals by Russinovich and Solomon](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qehtJAAACAAJ&dq=Windows+Internals+by+Russinovich+and+Solomon&cd=1) as a source for the high bits being zero.

Comment: Thanks Pete!
That’s exactly what I was looking for.
Here’s a relevant post on Mark Russinovich's blog:
http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx

Comment: This is all kinds of wrong.  First of all, a limit of 2^24 kernel handles does _not_ imply that handles will have values in the range [0, 2^24-1].  Second, the number of kernel handles is an internal implementation detail that is subject to change at any time (thus the title "Windows _Internals_").

Comment: Finally, the Winsock documentation is quite clear that values above 2^32 are allowed: "Windows Sockets handles have no restrictions, other than that the value INVALID_SOCKET is not a valid socket. Socket handles may take any value in the range 0 to INVALID_SOCKET–1" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740516(v=vs.85).aspx ).  The only saving grace is that since so many bad programmers have assumed SOCKET == int, Microsoft is unlikely to change their implementation because it would break all those programs.

Comment: @PeterRuderman this answer was correct with the documentation available at the time. If you want to edit to post to indicate that it is non longer the case in more recent implementations of Windows then be my guest.

Comment: The information is factually correct, but the conclusion does not follow.  Your post does not prove that it is safe to cast a SOCKET in an int in 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @PeterRuderman if the high bits are zero as Russinovich and Solomon state, why is it unsafe? I phrased it the way I did to indicate the reference was not a guarantee by MS but a second party observation.

Comment: Because while the high bits are zero (today), it's an implementation detail.  It's not contractual.  Microsoft could change this tomorrow.  Also keep in mind that the socket() function does _not_ promise to return a kernel handle, so even discussing the properties of kernel handles is beside the point.

Comment: @PeterRuderman Completely, yes. That much is implied by citing a non-MS source which documents the current (as of 2009) implementation rather than the API contract. If you think that needs to be spelt out, feel free to edit the post.

Comment: @PeterRuderman I disagree that assuming a socket is usable as an int is a sign of a bad programmer. Winsock is an implementation of the Berkley sockets API, albeit an incomplete and somewhat nonconforming one. This has always defined that a socket descriptor must be expressible as an int and indeed if one wishes to produce cross platform code using an int is the only way of doing so. Ultimately if Microsoft did decide to break this assumption they would be creating their own proprietary socket API which would break most cross-platform software.

Comment: @PeterRuderman  This software is not "bad", just because it does not wish to break compatibility with every other OS to cope with a theoretical Windows edge case.

Answer (score 11):

The simple answer to this question is no.  Take a look at the description of SOCKET values on MSDN [1]:

> Windows Sockets handles have no restrictions, other than that the value INVALID_SOCKET is not a valid socket. Socket handles may take any value in the range 0 to INVALID_SOCKET–1.

So clearly, the API allows all values in the range [0, 2^64 - 1) on 64-bit Windows.  And if the API ever returned a value greater than 2^32 - 1, assigning it to an int would result in handle truncation.  Also have a look at the description of the return value from the socket() function [2]:

> If no error occurs, socket returns a descriptor referencing the new socket.

Notice that it most *emphatically* does not promise to return a kernel handle.  This makes any discussion about the possible values for kernel handles moot.

All that being said, as of this writing, the socket() function really does return a kernel handle (or something indistinguishable from a kernel handle) [3] and kernel handles really are limited to 32-bits [4].  But keep in mind that Microsoft could change any of these things tomorrow without breaking their interface contracts.

However, since a doubtless large number of applications have taken a dependency on these particular implementation details (and more importantly, so has OpenSSL), Microsoft would likely think twice about making any breaking changes.  So go ahead and cast a SOCKET to an int.  Just keep in mind that this an inherently dangerous, bad practice, and is never justifiable in the name of expediency.

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740516(v=vs.85).aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742295(v=vs.85).aspx
4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384267(v=vs.85).aspx

**Edit (2018-01-29)**

Since this topic still seems to be of some interest, it's worth pointing out that it's quite easy to write portable sockets code in C++11 without resorting to questionable type casts:

```
using socket_t = decltype(socket(0, 0, 0));

socket_t s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

Comment: The OP was trying to invoke OpenSSL functions such as `SSL_set_fd(SSL *ssl, int fd);` where `fd` is the file descriptor for a socket you want use for SSL connections.  I don't know of any way to deal with this without casting.  Yes, it would be nice if OpenSSL introduced a generic type here that could be conditionalized, rather than forcing `int`, but... there's "expendiency", and there's "the only way to get it to work" :).

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * Even though sizeof(SOCKET) is 8, it's safe to cast it to int, because
 * the value constitutes an index in per-process table of limited size
 * and not a real pointer.
 */
```

This comment is correct. `SOCKET` = File handle on Windows NT series. I've never seen a 9x series 64 bit so there should be nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in current OpenSSL version 3 series, the doc already pointed out the solution [openssl doc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_set_fd.html)

NOTES:

On Windows, a socket handle is a 64-bit data type (UINT_PTR), which leads to a compiler warning (conversion from 'SOCKET' to 'int', possible loss of data) when passing the socket handle to SSL_set_*fd(). For the time being, this warning can safely be ignored, because although the Microsoft documentation claims that the upper limit is INVALID_SOCKET-1 (2^64 - 2), in practice the current socket() implementation returns an index into the kernel handle table, the size of which is limited to 2^24.

If this is correct, then casting Window's SOCKET into int should have no problem.