# Client/Server application: read() does not block on Windows under msys2/mingw64

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, network-programming, winsock

We have created an MWE showing a client/server. The networking is encapsulated in IPV4Socket.cc, Request.cc and Socket.cc

The complete code is on github: https://github.com/StevensDeptECE/simpleclientserver

The server opens a socket with a known port and waits. We send a 4 byte integer which gets through in Linux and replies with a message. Using Winsock the read on the server is not blocking, and returns a negative number. When `errno` is printed after the read, it claims that there is a bad file descriptor (on both the client and server side). Both read errors occur in Request.cc (line 17 and 32 for the server and client respectively).

```
// Send from server
void IPV4Socket::send(uint32_t reqn) { write(sckt, &reqn, sizeof(uint32_t)); }

// Send from client
void IPV4Socket::sendAndAwait(uint32_t reqn, Request &r) {
  send(reqn);
  r.handle(sckt);
}

// Client function (Request::handle) is the nearly the same, 
// but does not write back
void Request::handleServer(int returnsckt) {
  char buf[256];

  // FAILS HERE
  // first read incoming message from client
  int bytesRead = read(returnsckt, buf, 256);
  if (bytesRead < 1) perror("Read error: ");
  cout << "bytes read: " << bytesRead << ' ';
  
  // now write back to client
  const char answer[] = "testing";
  write(returnsckt, answer, sizeof(answer));
}

// Server socket constructor
IPV4Socket::IPV4Socket(uint16_t port) : Socket(port) {
  struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
  struct addrinfo hints;

  char port_string[8];
  itoa(port, port_string, 10);

  ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
  hints.ai_flags = 1;  // TODO: Originally AI_PASSIVE, convert to macro

  testResult(getaddrinfo(NULL, port_string, &hints, &result), __FILE__,
             __LINE__, Errcode::SOCKET);

  sckt = INVALID_SOCKET;
  sckt = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

  if (sckt == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    throw Ex1(Errcode::SOCKET);
  }

  // Setup the TCP listening socket
  if (bind(sckt, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(sckt);
    throw Ex1(Errcode::SOCKET_BIND);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(result);
  if (listen(sckt, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    cerr << "listen failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    closesocket(sckt);
    return;
  }
}

// Client socket constructor
IPV4Socket::IPV4Socket(const char *addr, uint16_t port) : Socket(addr, port) {
  // Same code as the Server socket constructor up to testresult(getaddrinfo)

  for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    sckt = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
    testResult(sckt == INVALID_SOCKET, __FILE__, __LINE__, Errcode::SOCKET);

    if (connect(sckt, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
      closesocket(sckt);
      sckt = INVALID_SOCKET;
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  testResult(sckt == INVALID_SOCKET, __FILE__, __LINE__, Errcode::SOCKET);
  freeaddrinfo(result);
}
```

Edit: I did not show it all in this simplified repository, but the original project we were working on (that most of this was drawn from) is now working. I did add some error handling to the socket I/O so that it now picks up when something goes wrong, but what ended up fixing it was replacing the calls to read/write with calls to send/recv. It looks like Winsock sockets (at the very least under mingw64), do not react well to read/write being used. This seems to have fixed most of the issues, but I'll throw another edit here if it breaks again.

Also, thank you to Remy for pointing me at that other question, I replaced the socket type with `using socket_t = decltype(socket(0, 0, 0));` so it now figures out the correct socket type independent of the OS.

Comment: On Windows, you should not use `int` to represents sockets, use WinSock's `SOCKET` type (alias for `UINT_PTR`) instead. See [Is it safe to cast SOCKET to int under Win64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953639/). More importantly, you really need to do proper error handling on all `read()` and `write()` calls. And handle the cases where they *can and will* return fewer bytes then requested, so they should be called in loops.

Comment: You are also ignoring end of stream, i.e. `recv()` returning zero, on which you should have stopped reading and closed the socket. It is impossible to write correct networking code while ignoring all return values, and specifically it is impossible without storing the result of `recv()` into a variable and testing it for (1) -1 and (2) zero, and then otherwise (3) using it as the (positive) count of bytes actually received. Don't write code like this.

Comment: "It looks like Winsock sockets (at the very least under mingw64), do not react well to read/write being used": Winsock sockets don't react *at all* to `read()/write()` being used. Only Unix and friends can do this.